# How to use xslt with checkbox and drop-down-menu on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I am using xslt to read a xml file and show its content in a table. I am using drop-down-menu for filtering some modelranges and a checkbox to filter identical rows.
Everything does work great on firefox but not on internet explorer. Drop down menu drops down and I can check my checkbox but I cannot filter anything. It is also not possible to change any entry of the tables in internet explorer. For example: I change cells with the last endtime to "-" but IE does not change this. I know there are a few "solutions" for some code working on internet explorer but any solution did not work for me.

Here is some relevant xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head><title>Secrets</title></head>

<body onload="script_for_all_functions();">

<table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:e2e2e2"></col>         
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:a5a5a5">
            <th rowspan="2">plane
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="script_for_all_functions()">
                     <option selected="selected">All</option>
                     <xsl:for-each select="logstore/Fahrzeug">
                        <option>
                         <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </option>
                     </xsl:for-each>                    
                </select>                   
            </th>   
            <th colspan="2" width="330">date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Secret
                <input type="checkbox" id="identicalSecrets" onchange="script_for_all_functions()"></input>
                <label for="identicalSecrets">hide identical secrets</label>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th align="center" style="background-color:a5a5a5">begin</th>
            <th align="center" style="background-color:a5a5a5">end</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="../Name"/></td>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="secret"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/C:/eclipse-workspace/adclasses/src/inbox/script_for_all_functions.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And some (not the complete) JavaScript code:

```
function script_for_all_functions() {
    // Variables
    let table, checkBox, filterCheckBox, filterDropDown, rows, cells, secret, modelRange, dropdown, rowCount;
    dropdown = document.getElementById('modelRangeDropdown');
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    rowCount = table.rows.length;
    checkBox=document.getElementById('identicalSecrets');
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");                
    filterCheckBox = checkBox.checked;
    filterDropDown = dropdown.value;
    let index = 0; 

    for (let row of rows) { // `for...of` loops through the NodeList
        // Verschiedene Spalteninhalte in Variabeln schreiben
        cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
        modelRange = cells[0] || null; 
        secret = cells[3]; 


        //=============================================================================================================
        //=============================================================================================================
        // Code for Drop-Down-Menu

        // if the Drop-Down-Menu is set to 'All', or this is the header row, or 1nd `td` text matches filter
        if (filterDropDown === "All" || !modelRange || (filterDropDown === modelRange.textContent)) {   
            if (filterCheckBox == false) {
                row.style.display = "table-row"; // show this row   
            }       
            else if (filterCheckBox == true) {
                if (index === 2) { 
                    row.style.display = "table-row"; // show this row
                }
                else if (index > 2) {
                    loop: { 
                        for (let i = 1; index - i > 1; i++) { 
                            if (modelRange.textContent === rows[index - i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent && secret.textContent === rows[index - i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].textContent) { 
                                rows[index - i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].firstChild.nodeValue = rows[index].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].textContent;
                                row.style.display = "none"; // hide this row
                            }                          
                            else { 
                                row.style.display = "table-row";
                                break loop;
                            }                      
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            row.style.display = "none"; // hide this row
        }
        //=============================================================================================================
        //=============================================================================================================


        //=============================================================================================================
        //=============================================================================================================
        // Code for Checkbox

        if (index > 2) { 
            if (filterCheckBox == true) { 
                loop: { 
                    for (let i = 1; index - i > 1; i++) { 
                        if (modelRange.textContent === rows[index - i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent && secret.textContent === rows[index - i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].textContent) { 
                            rows[index - i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].firstChild.nodeValue = rows[index].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].textContent;
                            row.style.display = "none"; // hide this row
                        }                                  
                        else { 
                            break loop;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else { 
                if (filterDropDown === "All") { 
                    row.style.display ="table-row";
                }
                else if (modelRange.textContent === filterDropDown){
                    row.style.display = "table-row"; 
                }
            }
        }
        //=============================================================================================================
        //=============================================================================================================

        index++; 
      } 

}
```

Comment: So which version(s) of IE do you target? Do you get any script errors in IE's developer console?

Comment: In any case, to ensure IE works as standards compliant as possible, I would suggest to add `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>` in the XSLT as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: I need to use this on IE 11. I don't get any script errors. I think my script didn't even start. Thanks I will try this.

Comment: This is not working at all. If I use ````<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>```` the browser ignores each color and JavaScript is still not working.

Comment: So what do the error consoles of the browsers tell you about your script and CSS, I am sure there will be errors or at least warnings.

Comment: For instance, run stuff like `background-color:e2e2e2` through any HTML or CSS validator and you will get an error for sure that you do not even have a valid value. It doesn't really make much sense to try to mix XSLT and HTML/CSS and Javascript if you don't start with valid HTML and CSS.

Comment: Okay if I take a look at the error consoles of the browser: One problem is my ``onchange="script_for_all_functions()"``. It says that the value of the feature "script_for_all_functions" is null or not defined. no function-object. How can I change that. I try to use transfer paramters or using return at the end of the JavaScript function.

Comment: Does that function work outside the context of an HTML document generated by XSLT? I am sure the error console will also tell you any syntax errors in the script code, does IE 11 support a construct like `let row of rows` at all? I guess you will have to take your code apart and start with something smaller and extend it step by step to work.

Comment: So it works great on Mozilla Firefox. So do you think the IE will need other syntax than Firefox? But based on the error above it is not even possible to go into the function. I do not think that IE will start JavaScript if the script ist empty. I think it will even throw that error.

Comment: An event handler can only call a function that has been parsed and compiled, if IE can't parse/compile a `let of` construct in your function then obviously no event handler will be able to call that function as that function has not been successfully been parsed.